# How to load the WebContent from a jar file in ServeletContext.xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jar

In my Spring application i have added another project as a `jar` file. I have added a separate `applicationContext.xml` for the project and imported it in main `applicationContext.xml`.

The problem arising is that the `WebContent` is not accessible from the `jar` file so getting the `404` error. The reason i have figured out is that `servletContext.xml` does not have the path of the `WebContent` resources present in `jar` file.

So my question is how to give the path of `WebContent` in `jar` file to `ServeletContext.xml`?

Do I need to create a separate `ServletContext.xml` for project in `jar` file?